# Using shell script to insert data into database

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

Using shell script to insert data into database, but getting a blank value in the base

Im trying to make massive and randomly insert values from it.

```
#!/bin/bash
N=1
ARRAY=( adssa asdsa fdgfd vcbxcxv )
for el in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do echo $el
done | shuf | head -$N

mysql -u root -pPass somebase << EOF
INSERT INTO sometable (name) VALUES ('$el');
SELECT * FROM site_user;
EOF
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler example that reproduces your problem:

```
for el in foo bar
do
  echo "$el"
done | head -n 1

echo "This is blank: $el"
```

This happens because the for loop and your mysql statement are not connected in any way. You have to get the data from your loop/pipeline to mysql.

The simplest way of doing this might be a `while read` loop:

```
for el in foo bar
do
  echo "$el"
done | head -n 1 | while read -r line
   do
      echo "This is not blank: $line"
   done
```

In your example, this would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
N=1
ARRAY=( adssa asdsa fdgfd vcbxcxv )
for el in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do echo $el
done | shuf | head -$N | while read -r line
do 
mysql -u root -pPass somebase << EOF
  INSERT INTO sometable (name) VALUES ('$line');
  SELECT * FROM site_user;
EOF
done
```

The simpler way would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
array=( adssa asdsa fdgfd vcbxcxv )
printf "INSERT INTO sometable (name) VALUES ('%s');\n" "${array[@]}" | \
  shuf | head -n $n | mysql -u root -pPass somebase
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your for loop using $(...) notation to get your output into the `el` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
N=1
ARRAY=( adssa asdsa fdgfd vcbxcxv )
el=$(for el in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do echo $el
done | shuf | head -$N)

mysql -u root -p1550005 stat << EOF
INSERT INTO site_user (name) VALUES ('$el');
SELECT * FROM site_user;
EOF
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion as long as you don't change the value of `N`